# Google Maps API: how do I make user-added markers permanent?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to create a map application which allows users to add their own pins. I want it to be an 'open' map where anyone with an account can add/edit pins on top of everyone else's.

With my limited knowledge of JavaScript, I have got to the point where anyone can add their pins, but they don't save (i.e. are removed once the application is reloaded). Only those I have put in manually (in the script) actually stick.

So, could anyone help me out?

How can I create some sort of 'database' (like in the custom map editor for google maps) which users can edit without having to actually put it in the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining `google`, `maps` and `api` doesn't mean you're talking about the Google Maps API.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear as you type in the tag autocomplete field.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

Answer (score 0):

look at jStorage http://www.jstorage.info/

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jstorage.js"></script>
<script>
   // Check if "key" exists in the storage
   var value = $.jStorage.get("key");
   if(!value){
       // if not - load the data from the server
       value = load_data_from_server()
       // and save it
       $.jStorage.set("key",value);
   }
</script>
```

Have two arrays saved by jStorage, lat and lng arrays, and then set markers by using a for loop and let it work through the arrays.